# How to execute an Ant task only when source files have been modified?

Tags: apache-flex, ant, dependencies

There must be an easy way to do this.  I build a Flex app using ant that depends on a SWC library, which works fine except that it rebuilds the library whether it needs to or not.  How do I tell ant to only run the task if any of the sources files of the library (*.as, *.mxml) are newer than the SWC?

I've looked at <dependset> but it only seems to delete files, not determine whether a task should be run or not.  <depend> seems to expect a one-to-one relationship between the source and target files rather than a one-to-many relationship -- I have many input files and one output file, but no intermediate object files.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may use the Ant [uptodate task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) to create a property, and execute your other target only if that property is set.

I don't know much about flex, but you probably want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="compile">

   <target name="checkforchanges">
      <uptodate property="nochanges">
         <srcfiles dir="." includes="**/*.as"/>
         <srcfiles dir="." includes="**/*.mxml"/>
         <mapper to="applicaton.flex"/>
      </uptodate>
   </target>

   <target name="compile" depends="checkforchanges" unless="nochanges">
      ...
   </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Here's what I'm using now:

<code> <uptodate property="playerlib.notRequired" targetfile="${playerlib.swc}" >
   <srcfiles dir= "${src.dir}" includes="**/*.as"/>
   <srcfiles dir= "${src.dir}" includes="**/*.mxml"/>
   <srcfiles dir= "${basedir}" includes="**/*.xml"/>
 </uptod

Comment: I believe in the "compile" target, you should use "unless" instead of "if".  I could be wrong...

Comment: You're right. I got the wrong idea here (and needed some time to realize it). Thanks. I named the property the wrong way also. I will change my answer.

Answer (score 10):

The [OutOfDate](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html) task from the [ant contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net) library is IMO much cleaner than the Ant `uptodate` option. The reason is that you have to define additional targets just to set the property.

The solution with Ant contrib (from their example page):

```
<outofdate>
    <sourcefiles>
        <pathelement path="build.xml"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}"/>
    </sourcefiles>
    <targetfiles path="${jrun.file}"/>
    <sequential>
        <mkdir dir="${build.bin.dir}"/>
        <echo file="${jrun.file}" message="java -cp ${jrun.path} $*"/>
        <chmod file="${jrun.file}" perm="ugo+rx"/>
    </sequential>
</outofdate>
```

Everything is kept nicely inside one single target.