# Running an Ant exec task only for modified files

Tags: php, ant, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm creating a build script for a large PHP application. I'm using an Ant script, being run by Jenkins.

I want to include tools such as PHP_CodeSniffer and PHPMD (PHP Mess Detector) in the build script, so I have code like this:

```
<target name="php-codesniffer">
    <exec executable="phpcs" dir="${basedir}" output="${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml">
        <arg line="--report=checkstyle --standard=PEAR ${basedir}/"/>
    </exec>
</target>
<target name="phpmd">
    <exec executable="phpmd" dir="${basedir}" output="${basedir}/build/logs/phpmd.xml">
        <arg line="${basedir} xml codesize,unusedcode,naming"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

However both these tools take an excessively long period of time to run, even on small subsets of our code base, so I'm trying to find ways I can use them, but without the performance penalty.

My current thought is to run them only on files which have been modified in the current build, but I don't know Ant well enough to get it to do this.

So the question is how can I modify the above Ant targets such that the `<exec>` calls only run for files which have been modified in the current build? (or alternatively in the last X minutes if Ant doesn't know about the current build).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the question [How to execute ANT tasks on only files that have been modified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/497850/127035), and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/761979/127035) which illustrates use of the [modified selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#modified).

It looks like [phpcs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.usage.php) takes either a list of files and/or a directories. It recurses into directories.

If you are going to stick with specifying a single directory and have phpcs recurse into it, then you could first find target files (using the modified selector) and copy to a temporary dir. Then point phpcs to that dir. One downside of that is that you are adding disk i/o for the copy into your build time.

Probably better, you could [pathcovert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) a fileset selected using the modified selector. Use a space as the `pathsep` for this. That will give you a property the value of which is a space separated list of your target files. The downside of this one could be that you end up with too long a list of args.

---

To answer your follow up question in comments, here is a simple example of how you could use pathconvert to create a space-separated list of files and pass them to an executable (in this case the Windows dir command):

```
<project default="test">

  <target name="test">
    <pathconvert property="file.list" pathsep=" ">
      <fileset dir="src">
        <include name="a.txt"/>
        <include name="b.txt"/>
      </fileset>
    </pathconvert>
    <echo message="file.list: ${file.list}"/>
    <exec executable="cmd">
      <arg value="/c"/>
      <arg value="dir"/>
      <arg line="${file.list}"/>
    </exec>
  </target>

</project>
```

(Note that I used `line` rather than `value` to pass the file list in the `exec`.)

Here is the content of the dir which files are selected from (one is not included):

```
C:\tmp\ant>dir src
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1773-83D6

 Directory of C:\tmp\ant\src

30/11/2011  12:21    <DIR>          .
30/11/2011  12:21    <DIR>          ..
30/11/2011  12:09                 0 a.txt
30/11/2011  12:09                 0 b.txt
30/11/2011  12:09                 0 c.txt
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  435,642,912,768 bytes free
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\tmp\ant>ant
Buildfile: C:\tmp\ant\build.xml

test:
     [echo] file.list: C:\tmp\ant\src\a.txt C:\tmp\ant\src\b.txt
     [exec]  Volume in drive C has no label.
     [exec]  Volume Serial Number is 1773-83D6
     [exec]
     [exec]  Directory of C:\tmp\ant\src
     [exec]
     [exec] 30/11/2011  12:09                 0 a.txt
     [exec]
     [exec]  Directory of C:\tmp\ant\src
     [exec]
     [exec] 30/11/2011  12:09                 0 b.txt
     [exec]                2 File(s)              0 bytes
     [exec]                0 Dir(s)  435,642,896,384 bytes free

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Re your first suggestion (copying to a temp dir): yes; that was how I was thinking of doing it. I did see that previous question, but wasn't sure how to relate it to my case. Your answer has helped me with that, so thank you. Re the `pathconvert` suggestion: that does sound better. However I'm finding the Ant documentation quite hard to follow. Could you give me an example that includes how I would use the generated path within the `<exec>`? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Very much appreciated. I've accepted the answer (can't upvote yet; not enough score). I'll play around with it some more and see how things go. I think you've given me plenty to be working with. Thanks.