# how to compile only changed source files using ANT

Tags: java, performance, ant, compilation

I am trying to write ant build for compiling source folder here is my script **target** for compiling.

```
 <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="true">
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>

    </target>
```

In my project I have near about 1000 `.java` files. When ever a single `.java` file is changed  above target tends to compile all `.java` files. Which make development very slow. I just want to know is there any way or code to change the behavior of task to compile only modified or changed `.java` file rather than all `.java` file.

Please help me.

Comment: check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497850/how-to-execute-ant-tasks-on-only-files-that-have-been-modified

Comment: I checked that. that is for executing task not compile.

Comment: We want to compile only changed file

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov no i am trying to compile from command prompt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I understand, compiling only the modified java files is the default behavior of ant javac task. Ant uses the timestamp of a .java file and its corresponding .class file to determine if the a Java file needs to be recompiled. I have used it in many projects and never have issues.

Here are a few things you can check

1. Is your source tree directory structure matching your Java package
   structure? Please see [Why does ant always recompile all my Java
   files?](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#always-recompiles). This is probably the number 1 reason since it is in the FAQ.
2. I see your `compile` target depends on `init` target? What does the `init` target do? Does it depends on any `clean` target or does it cleanup the .class files?
3. What is your ant version? Can you try a different ant version to see if you still have the same problem?
4. If none of the above fixes your issue, after the compilation, can you manually check the .class file timestamp and compare it with the timestamp of the corresponding .java file?

Answer (score 1):

So if you are not deleting the classes directory in any dependent task say 'clean' the javac task inherently compiles only the changed java files. It is an out of the box feature that javac task provides. Hope it helps.