# Bash shell build java application using ant

Tags: java, bash, ant

I wrote a bash shell that runs a java application. To automatize the process I want to first add **ant** to build the java application. However, I don't want to rebuilt the existing application if there aren't any changes in *java files. I'm lost as what is a good way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ant [`javac` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) does exactly that:

> Compiles a Java source tree.
>
> The source and destination directory will be recursively scanned for Java source files to compile. *Only Java files that have no corresponding .class file or where the class file is older than the .java file will be compiled.*

So just create a buildfile that uses `javac` and have the bash script call Ant to compile before running the application. You can also use Ant itself to run the application by using the [`java` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. In my build.xml I have `  <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="GRAB.classpath"/>
        </javac>
` I assume that's where Ant javac is used.

Comment: Yes this is how it is usually called. But I don't think you need to specify the `src` element if you're already using the `source="${source}"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Javac task of ant should be doing exactly that. Can check the answer to the question link below which provides little more detail

[how to compile only changed source files using ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128824/how-to-compile-only-changed-source-files-using-ant)